# Summary stats for wide data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there an efficient way to to calculate summary stats for each fruit where that fruit row is True?

```
df   comment  type      score    apple   banana   pear   
0     dfsd    new        0.4     True    False    True     
1     sdfs    low        0.3     False   True     False 
2     sdddfs   low       0.2     False   True     False    
3     sdsfs    low       0.8     True    True     False    
4     ddds    low        0.1     True    True     True

...
```

I've tried:

```
fruits = ['apple','banana','pear']

for fruit in fruits:
    df1 = df.loc[df.f'{fruit}', :]
    df1.describe()
```

Expected Output:

```
fruit
        count     mean_score   std_score  
apple               
banana              
pear
```

Comment: what are the values for count, mean_score and std deviation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the required `fruits` columns then get the corresponding `score` for each fruit column and mask the `False` value finally use `describe` to get the descriptive statistics:

```
s = ['count', 'mean', 'std']
stats = df[fruits].apply(lambda m: df['score'].mask(~m)).describe().T[s]
```

---

```
print(stats)

        count      mean       std
apple     3.0  0.433333  0.351188
banana    4.0  0.350000  0.310913
pear      2.0  0.250000  0.212132
```

Comment: Thanks! Is T short for "transform"?

Comment: @asd yes it is :)

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work I just realised. I've updated the expected output. Each fruit is only true once in the df, so the count should be 1

Comment: @asd hmm..how you got mean 0.4?

Comment: So for each fruit, keep only the rows where that fruit's column has a True. Then take the mean and count

Comment: @asd whats the `s. deviation` in that case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221366/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-asd).

Comment: Would you mind explaining the lambda function: is it for each column find where an observation has a score that isn't NaN?

Answer (score 0):

A general way to do this that doesnt rely on df.describe happening to have the stats you are after is:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['apple','banana','pear']).agg({'type':['count','mean','std']})
```

will get you the count, mean, and std for each  fruit.\

In response to a comment, you can rework the indices to get just a fruit per row by:

```
df2.index = [df2.index.names[i] for j in range(len(df2.index.names)) for i,x in enumerate(df2.index[j]) if x ]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work because for each fruit it shows the True False columns for all possibilities of that fruit